# How do I create a regular expression to split lines, except if there is a slash?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using "my-string".split("\n") to split a string into an array of lines, and that is working nicely.

However now I need to add support for a continuation character "\".

I would like to change my split so that it splits the string into lines on '\n' *except* if there is a "\" character just before the "\n"

So for example "THIS\nIS\nA\nTEST" would split into "THIS", "IS", "A\nTEST"

At first I thought I would go and replace all of the instances of instances of  /\n with a placeholder, then change them back at the end. But that is too much processing. The string can be pretty long, and can consume many lines.

Comment: You say '\' is the continuation character, yet you're using '/' in your example. Which one is it?

Comment: `"x=12\ny=2\\n3".split(/\n/)` works isn't it?

Comment: @t0mppa - You are right, I corrected the question

Comment: @anubhava no, that splits even on \\n, which it should not

Comment: @VictorGrazi: [Check this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anbw75ue/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called negative look behind. This e.g. matches b's that are not preceded by a's:
`(?<!a)b`

So, what you need is
`(?<!\\)\n`

**Update**
JavaScript does not support negative look behind. Unfortunately, there is no single best strategy to deal with it. Here is a nice blog listing all possible approaches: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript

I personally would go with splitting on "\n", i.e. avoid regexp altogether, and then join the strings in the array that have "\" at the end. For this particular case and if continuations are exception rather than the rule it will provide the best performance.

Comment: Hmm, this does not work. Trying "x=12\ny=2\\n3".split("(?<!\\)\n") but it is just returning an array of length one containing the original string